# Is there anyway to establish connection between multiple client and sftp server through public/private key authentication?

Tags: java

Is there anyway to get private key as string rather than file location and can we authenticate sftp.If so help with it.If we want to authenticate through public/private key means the ./ssh/id_rsa file must be in our local client which is going to read and authenticate it? I am using jsch Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than trying to get private key from the client . Generate the public-private key pair and give that to the client's sftp servers. This will be helpful for those who use sftp-ssh connection in their product or Appilication.

Thanks,